# how to save a matter number typed in tkinter textbox to a txt file and each new saved number to a new line

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

Every time I save a new matter number from the tkinter textbox to the txt file, it replaces the previous one. I need it to save on the next line. Below is the code I've tried. Please assist.
Thanks and All the best.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry("700x250")


def save_text():
    text_file = open("matters.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(my_text_box.get(1.0, END))
    text_file.close()


label = Label(window, text = 'Save the matter number  Matter number:').grid(row=3, column=1,)

my_text_box = Text(window, height=2, width=40).grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=12)

save = Button(window, text="Save matter", command=save_text).grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid them:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in "append" mode `'a'` instead of "write" mode `'w'` if you want to add content to an existing file. Try this instead:

```
def save_text():
    with open('matters.txt', 'a') as text_file:  # 'a' specifies 'append' mode
        text_file.write(my_text_box.get(1.0, END))
```

I've used a context manager here (the `with` statement) to make opening and closing the file a little cleaner as well

Comment: Thanks, I want it to automatically create the file first, thereafter append

Comment: Happy to help! This will create the file if it doesn't already exist. If this answer worked for you, please mark it as "Accepted" so that others know this question has been answered.